# Можно ли использовать "не" и "против" в одном предложении?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Можно ли использовать "не" и "против" в одном предложении? Например: **Международный отдел не имеет возражений против визита доктора.**

Comment: Прописные пошли лесом?

Comment: Можно использовать то и другое даже рядом (в любом предложении): "... отдел не против...".

Comment: А как Вам нравится "возражать против"?  В обычном представлении  это два отрицания,  поэтому сочетание похоже на плеоназм: возражать собеседнику и возражать против  его аргументов.

Comment: @shampar, Не надеясь на автора, я добавил прописные. Но обидно. Как будто человек пришел к тебе за советом по поводу хороших манер и ноги на стол положил.

Comment: "Князь уже **не возражал против визита** и следовал послушно за генералом, чтобы не раздражать его, в твердой надежде, что генерал Соколович и все семейство его мало-по-малу испарится как мираж и окажутя несуществующими", - Ф. М. Достоевский "Идиот"

Comment: @Jasmin
Думаю, что можно _возражать **против** намерения или действия_ (говоря о несогласии), либо _возражать **на** аргумент или высказывание_ (противопоставляя что-либо). У Розенталя в справочнике" Управление в русском языке" о такой сочетаемости не говорится, но примеры для В. "против чего" и "на что" приведены именно с таким различием: возразить против внесённого предложения и возразить на замечания оппонента.

Comment: Я  не считаю это выражение неправильным, а просто спрашиваю: это плеоназм или нет? А если да, то почему он используется в языке и какая в нем необходимость?

Comment: На мой взгляд, в выражении "возражать против аргументов собеседника" заключён не плеоназм, а возможная смысловая ошибка. Такое выражение корректно в смысле "выражать несогласие с _характером_ аргументов, приводимых собеседником (уходит от темы, переходит на личности и пр.)", и оно становится смысловой ошибкой, если имелось в виду простое приведение контраргументов (возразить **на**), а не призыв говорить по существу и т. п. Такую ошибку может выявить контекст.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сказать так: Международный отдел не возражает **против визита доктора**.

Сочетание ***не возражать против чего-либо*** имеет значение "быть согласным с чем-либо." Оно   активно применяется в русском языке (в Нацкорпусе встречается 65 раз), например:

Ни один ревнитель чистоты языка **не возражает против** слова «известь», а ведь это не что иное, как искажение греческого слова «азбэстэс». [Л. В. Успенский. Слово о словах (1971)]

Витте был молчалив и подавлен и заявил только, что он **не возражает против** предложенной меры.... [В. Н. Коковцов. Из моего прошлого / Части 1-4 (1933)]

Он **не возражает против** встречи с Вами. [Эльдар Рязанов. Подведенные итоги (2000)]

О предлоге ***против***

**Против** ― это наречный предлог, он указан в словаре: **ВОЗРАЗИТЬ против чего / на что.** Возразить против внесённого предложения.

**Против ― многозначный предлог**, в сочетании ***возразить против*** у него нет отрицательного значения, он означает  "то, что находится **перед кем-либо (чем-либо)".**

ПРОТИВ 1. **предлог прямо перед кем-либо (чем-либо).** 2. предлог навстречу, в обратном, противоположном направлении. 3. предлог вопреки, наперекор кому-либо (чему-либо). 4. предлог для борьбы с кем-либо (чем-либо), противодействия чему-то. 5. предлог в сравнении, в сопоставлении с кем-либо (чем-либо). [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/против](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2)

**Также из словаря:**

II. ПРОТИВ нареч. С возражением. На обсуждении выступил п. Голосовали все п. // При обозначении предмета, лица, явления, по отношению к которому испытывается, проявляется что-л. отрицательное, враждебное. **Ничего не иметь п. публикации статьи (быть согласным).** Настроить себя п. соседей (враждебно).